# Need regex for the pattern in URL

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a web crawler for some specific needs and need to tell whether a particular pattern is present in a string or not.

Supose the url which is in `String` format is like below:

```
/life-is-what-you-make-it/dask23442knk24?pid=9788129124913&ref=9090912adqeqeqeqeq
```

If `pid` contains `only digits` (here you can see `pid=9788129124913` so it should return true for this) than do something. Can somebody help me in getting the regex for that. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I have been doing this by `substring()` but its too tedious so i thought of `regex` but could not comprehend it to write it by myself. Very soon i will look into regex stuff after this long pending stuff finishes. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: @downvoter please at least put a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex:

```
\bpid=\d+(&|$)
```

spelled: After a word boundary, "pid=" followed by some digits, then either an ampersand or the end of the string.

(Be sure to use Matcher.find, not Matcher.matches)

Comment: @kocko Why would it not work?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thoght the question is different.

Comment: What if pid is the last parameter and therefore not followed by an ampersand?

Comment: Yes, @n.st, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed it. (The edit hasn't been approved yet, though.)

Comment: Unfortunately, @n.st, your proposed solution would report false positive on "pid=1234.7689". We need a way to express & or end of string

Comment: You're right. Use `(&|$)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To get just numeric value of the **pid** parameter, use regex pattern `(?<=\bpid=)\d+(?=&|$)`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

However in Java you have to double each escape character `\`, so the pattern is

```
(?<=\\bpid=)\\d+(?=&|$)
```

---

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\bpid=)\\d+(?=&|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Test this demo code **[here](http://ideone.com/8F9BMg)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about validating the rest of the URL, and only want to match/grab the `pid` value, you can use:

`\?pid=(\d+)`

This also returns the `pid` value in the first group.

Comment: This will return a false positive for any pid that starts with at least one digit, but contains some letters after that.